# Generating polygons with a target area from points using st_buffer

Tags: r, buffer, sf

I have some point geometries which I want to turn into polygons using `st_buffer`. For each point I have a target area that the resulting polygon should have. Here's an example using R:

```
library(sf)
# Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.7.2, PROJ 9.3.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

pt <- st_sfc(st_point(c(160,2)), crs = 4326)
target_area <- 10
radius <- sqrt(target_area / pi)
buffered <- st_buffer(pt, units::set_units(radius, "km"))

units::set_units(target_area, "km²") - st_area(buffered)
# -0.1087395 [km²]
```

Is there a way to tweak this workflow so I can minimize the difference between the calculated and target area? A range of 0.01km² would be preferable for my case.

Comment: I think you need to create your geometry in a projected CRS, not 4326.

Comment: It all depends on how precise you want this - either a flat earth model (projected CRS) where A = pi r^2 is true, or you need to work out the radius of a spherical cap that returns the given area (not too hard) or an ellipsoidal section, which might be very hard, and maybe found by interval bisection to any degree of accuracy, and will require a different radius depending on the latitude...

Comment: @Llaves: I want to avoid projected CRS in this case, since I have a lot of points scattered over the earth.

Comment: @Spacedman: Thanks, I'll do that to improve accuracy a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the lege artis way for buffer (and area, come to that) calculations is to use a projected CRS appropriate for your area of interest.

However, for the sake of technical curiosity, you may consider using `terra::buffer()` instead of `sf::st_buffer()`. It will give you a smoother, more circular buffer than {sf} when used in context of S2 geometry (i.e. unprojected).

For more detail have a look at this earlier answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70152564/7756889

Just keep in mind that the `terra::buffer()` expects distance in meters for unprojected CRS, not an {units} object like `sf::st_buffer()`, and will not accept kilometers.

```r
library(sf)

pt <- st_sfc(st_point(c(160,2)), crs = 4326)

target_area <- 10 * 1000 ^2 #  terra expects meters, not kilometers

radius <- sqrt(target_area / pi)

buffered <- pt %>% 
  terra::vect() %>% 
  terra::buffer(width = radius) %>% 
  st_as_sf()

units::set_units(units::set_units(target_area, "m²") - st_area(buffered), "km²") 
# -0.003488407 [km²]
```